# AWS Cognito attributes OpenID

Tags: amazon-web-services, attributes, openid, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to login in Cognito via another OAuth.
I added OIDC provider to Cognito Userpool. I setup attribute mappings for this new OIDC "email" -> "Email". In attributes permissions are all permission checked for read and also write.

I can successfully log in through cognito via this OIDC, but there is no attribute email in user. Any idea why ?

I tried manually hit user info endpoint with access token and in response there is email. I dont know why Cognito is not able to get it.

I tried also use Auth0 as OIDC provider and everything works fine, but I can't see any difference between them.

This is OIDC provider: https://authtest.sportlink.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: I'm having the same issues with Intuit OpenID, did you resolve yours?

Comment: I didn't do anthing, jst contacted OpenID provider and they changed something

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is that perhaps the scopes are missing email.

If you edit the OIDC connection make sure that `email` is in the "Authorize scope" section.

I also use OIDC and it does map email for me.

[image]

Comment: I got there `openid email profile`
I tried OpenID Auth0 and it works properly, can it be issue with this specific OIDC ?
Only difference i can see is that auth0 include email in id_token

Comment: @Dasio are you saying the id_token or access_token are missing the email? I don't think you can ever get any attributes beyond sub and username in the access_token that amazon issues.

Comment: In this custom OIDC there is no `email` in `id_token` just sub etc ... In Auth0 `id_token` there is `email`.
I'm not saying about Cognito Tokens. In Cognito console, I can't see the email in users from this custom OIDC, but I can see emails from Auth0 OIDC.

Comment: I am able to map things like `aud` which are in `id_token` from OIDC(not from cognito), could it be AWS bug ?